Delinquency rate on student loans in the United States
Why is the delinquency rate (90 days+) on student loans at an all time low in the United States (as illustrated in the last Household debt and credit report of the New York Fed).
For most borrowers, the first payment after the payment pause ended was due in October 2023 so it seems to me that it should be up by now. Could it be the Federal Student Loan Debt Relief ?
Thanks !

This article suggests that yes, administration policy is having a big impact
https://www.politico.com/news/2023/12/15/forty-percent-of-student-loan-borrowers-missed-payments-in-october-00132062
